# Where is the type @> in scalaz source code?

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7

I've been reading the source for scalaz's Lenses, which you can find at https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Lens.scala

Starting at **line 303**, there are functions that return values of type **@>[A,B]**. Is this type an alias for **Lens**? This makes sense to me from context and from the shape of the symbols, which might represent a beam of light going into a circular lens.

But then why are other functions returning **Lens[A,B]** instead of the funky alias? I did a search for this symbol in the file, and in the files imported by Lens.scala, but to no avail.

Where can I find the definition of **@>**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's a type alias, and most of these convenience type aliases—including `@>`, but also things like `Reader`, `State`, and even `Lens` itself, which is a type alias for `LensFamily[...]`—live in [the `scalaz` package object](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/package.scala#L202) in `core/src/main/scala/scalaz/package.scala`.

The fact that `A @> B` is used in some places and `Lens[A, B]` in others is almost certainly just the result of historical accident and the preferences of particular authors.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think to look in the package object. Thanks!